# Swift 3 conversion - function in capture list

Tags: swift3, capture

I am trying to convert a project from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3.
Code before the convertor was:

Code in Swift 2.3

```
..., handler: { [performSegueWithIdentifier] _ in
    performSegueWithIdentifier("Help Segue", sender: nil)
}
```

After convertor, in Swift 3.0, code become:

```
..., handler: { [performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)] _ in
    performSegueWithIdentifier("Help Segue", sender: nil)
}
```

But I have a compile error:

```
'Expected 'weak', 'unowned', or no specifier in capture list'
```

What I have tried:

- remove parameters, but it seems that `Expression type 'Void' (aka '()') is ambiguous without more context`.

Answer (score 0):

The error: 
'Expression type 'Void' ...' is related to second line:

`performSegue(withIdenfifier: "Help Segue", sender: nil)`

So, all will become:

```
handler: { [performSegue] _ in
    performSegue("Help Segue", nil)
})
```